# Sentence ending in ～でさ

Tags: particles, slang

hello, my lovelies! I found this from a song:

> 嘘つくのは得意なんだ
>
> でも、本音は少し苦手**でさ**
>
> おかしいね、いつだって
>
> 本当の話が一番嘘臭いんだよ

I'm going to guess that it's a masculine or slang form of である with the さ particle attached for emphasis (the singer is male). Just to be sure there are no other misunderstandings getting in the way though, here is my rough translation:

> Telling lies is my forte
>
> But I'm kind of bad at (telling) the truth
>
> Funny, right?
>
> How my true tales are always the biggest stinking lies

So, I'm basically assuming that でさ here is just a slang way to say だ or です, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think this particular use of さ is very masculine; the more masculine  でも、本音は少し苦手さ would mean something a bit different.

Comment: The only other usage of さ I can think of is used with 形容詞. Like 暑さ... Or are you saying でさ itself is one particle or word?

Comment: I always thought さ was a casual sentence ending, which I occasionally here to help add an extra syllable in songs. Source: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/sentence_ending

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense now...but that still doesn't explain the で and why it is the way it is. Why not ださ?

Comment: @MissLavelle That use of さ replaces だ. This さ is the さ of でもさ、変じゃない？

Comment: Usually I'd advise not to take lyrics as good examples of grammar usage since they tend to use rare or even wrong grammar(keep that in mind when you read them), but in this case it just seems like でさ is being used as nothing more than syllable filler. There isn't much meaning behind it and there is very little point in trying to make sense of it. で and さ are both really common in speech as well as fillers without any meaning.

Comment: @strawberryjam True enough. I do always like to be sure it's nothing grammatical though, but rather, simply a stylistic choice for the song.

Comment: @Nothingatall Ahhh, I see there. I've just seen でもさ more often than this though, soooo I was like, "Huh?" Haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

で is a conjunctive (or adverbial) form of copula (だ or である) and さ is a filler. (Since this さ follows a conjunctive form, it's not a sentence ending particle.) It's not particularly either masculine or feminine. The verb being the conjunctive form means that the sentence doesn't end there.

Comment: Hmm, I've noticed in songs where the sentence would end they make it て形 (probably to make things flow) and such so what you're saying makes sense.

Comment: It's not limited to songs. It's just common in speaking since we speak words while thinking, not after finishing thought.

Comment: True, true. Guess that explains why I often see Japanese people end with と思って a lot. Thanks for helping me out!